# Adding image to a button in WPF C#, image not appearing

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a button in my windows 8 desktop app, which will have an image and a text block. I have to do this using C# coding.
My code is as follows,

```
            Button btn = new Button();               
            StackPanel btnContentPanel = new StackPanel();
            btnContentPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(newUri(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\download.jpg"));
            img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            btnContentPanel.Children.Add(img);

            TextBlock txBlock = new TextBlock();
            txBlock.Text = "My Button";
            btnContentPanel.Children.Add(txBlock);               

            btn.Content = btnContentPanel;
```

This is not giving any error but the image is not getting displayed. If I add another text block in place of the image, then its appearing, but not the image.

Am I missing anything ? Please help, thank you.

Comment: The code should work as it is. Things that you should check: Try a different image. If with that it works, then the image file itself could be the source of your problem. Do you have any styles defined in your app? Maybe there is something that sets - for example - the visibility of that image to hidden or collapsed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building your button like this:

```
Button btn= new Button
{
    Width = 30,
    Height = 30,
    Content = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Images\download.jpg"))
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a 'missing' image there are several things to consider:

When Xaml can't locate a resource it might ignore it (when it won't throw a XamlParseException)

The Resource must be properly added and defined:

make sure it exists in your project where expected.

Make sure it is built with your project as a Resource.

(Right click -> Properties -> BuildAction='Resource')

[image]

Another thing to try in similar cases, which is also useful for reusing of the image (or any other resource):

Define your Image as a Resource in your Xaml:

```
<UserCondrol.Resources>
     <Image x:Key="MyImage" Source.../>
</UserControl.Resources>
And later use it in your desired control/controls:

<Button Content={StaticResource MyImage} />
```

Comment: The image is located at the proper place. I checked in build action, built action is "content". I changed to "embedded resources" as I could not find "resource" option. But still it didn't work. Basically my button is dynamically created and its contents are set dynamically. So i tried to put the text and the image via StackPanel. The only issue  is with the image.

Comment: Add It to your resources